# In Bigquery, I need to merge a historical data table with the transactional data table like an audit table without using stored procedure or function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I will be very grateful if you can help me with this problem that I have not been able to solve.

**Context**: Bigquery, but I can't use stored procedures or functions.

**Transactional data table:** I have a table with the information in its last state for each id (figure A).

*Transactional data table:*

| id | nrut | vendor_name | state | bedi | flag | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 888724 | 413 | john smith | dispatched | null | null | 2019-12-28 09:41:17 |
| 873060 | 764 | louis reed | in transit | T | A | 2018-11-19 15:26:32 |

**Change data table:** on the other hand, I have a table with the sequence of changes that affect the first over time, **but only contains the changes after the creation of the original data**. So, for the final audit data table I have to put the creation_date as the first change_date. (figure B).

*Change data table:*

| id | column_change | change_date | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 873060 | vendor_name | 2021-09-24 11:50:06 | mary lantz | louis reed |
| 888724 | state | 2022-12-22 06:00:57 | received | dispatched |
| 888724 | vendor_name | 2022-12-22 06:00:57 | bob williams | john smith |
| 873060 | state | 2023-02-21 18:36:45 | store | in transit |
| 873060 | flag | 2023-02-21 18:36:45 | null | A |
| 873060 | bedi | 2023-02-21 18:36:45 | null | F |
| 873060 | bedi | 2023-02-23 15:15:01 | F | T |
| 873060 | nrut | 2023-02-23 15:15:01 | 123 | 764 |

**Final audit data table:** the goal is to have a complete audit table that has the state of the table over time (figure C).

*Final audit data table:*

| id | nrut | vendor_name | state | bedi | flag | creation_date | change_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 873060 | 123 | mary lantz | store | null | null | 2018-11-19 15:26:32 | 2018-11-19 15:26:32 |
| 873060 | 123 | louis reed | store | null | null | 2018-11-19 15:26:32 | 2021-09-24 11:50:06 |
| 873060 | 123 | louis reed | in transit | F | A | 2018-11-19 15:26:32 | 2023-02-21 18:36:45 |
| 873060 | 764 | louis reed | in transit | T | A | 2018-11-19 15:26:32 | 2023-02-23 15:15:01 |
| 888724 | 413 | bob williams | received | null | null | 2019-12-28 09:41:17 | 2019-12-28 09:41:17 |
| 888724 | 413 | john smith | dispatched | null | null | 2019-12-28 09:41:17 | 2022-12-22 06:00:57 |

As I show in the images bellow, the creation date must correspond to the first change date.

In the change data table, there can have several rows for the same change date, which must be consolidated as a single row in the result.

**Colored tables for better understanding:**

I have colored the images to hopefully help your better understanding. If the images cannot be seen or any doubt persists, please let me know. Thank you very much in advance.

*Transactional data table coloured:*

[image: figure A: transactional data table]

*Change data table coloured:*

[image: figure B: change data table]

*Final audit data table coloured:*

[image: figure C: final audit data table]

**SQL scripts for data creation in Bigquery:**

*Transactional data table creation script:*

```
SELECT 888724 AS id, 413 AS nrut, 'john smith' AS vendor_name, 'dispatched' AS state, null AS bedi, null AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2019-12-28 09:41:17') AS creation_date UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 764 AS nrut, 'louis reed' AS vendor_name, 'in transit' AS state, 'T' AS bedi, 'A' AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2018-11-19 15:26:32') AS creation_date
```

*Change data table creation script:*

```
SELECT 873060 AS id, 'vendor_name' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2021-09-24 11:50:06') AS change_date, 'mary lantz' AS old_value, 'louis reed' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 888724 AS id, 'state' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2022-12-22 06:00:57') AS change_date, 'received' AS old_value, 'dispatched' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 888724 AS id, 'vendor_name' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2022-12-22 06:00:57') AS change_date, 'bob williams' AS old_value, 'john smith' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 'state' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-21 18:36:45') AS change_date, 'store' AS old_value, 'in transit' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 'flag' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-21 18:36:45') AS change_date, null AS old_value, 'A' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 'bedi' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-21 18:36:45') AS change_date, null AS old_value, 'F' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 'bedi' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-23 15:15:01') AS change_date, 'F' AS old_value, 'T' AS new_value UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 'nrut' AS column_change, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-23 15:15:01') AS change_date, '123' AS old_value, '764' AS new_value
```

*Final audit table data creation script (as desired):*

```
SELECT 873060 AS id, 123 AS nrut, 'mary lantz' AS vendor_name, 'store' AS state, null AS bedi, null AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2018-11-19 15:26:32') AS creation_date, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2018-11-19 15:26:32') AS change_date UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 123 AS nrut, 'louis reed' AS vendor_name, 'store' AS state, null AS bedi, null AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2018-11-19 15:26:32') AS creation_date, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2021-09-24 11:50:06') AS change_date UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 123 AS nrut, 'louis reed' AS vendor_name, 'in transit' AS state, 'F' AS bedi, 'A' AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2018-11-19 15:26:32') AS creation_date, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-21 18:36:45') AS change_date UNION ALL
SELECT 873060 AS id, 764 AS nrut, 'louis reed' AS vendor_name, 'in transit' AS state, 'T' AS bedi, 'A' AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2018-11-19 15:26:32') AS creation_date, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2023-02-23 15:15:01') AS change_date UNION ALL
SELECT 888724 AS id, 413 AS nrut, 'bob williams' AS vendor_name, 'received' AS state, null AS bedi, null AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2019-12-28 09:41:17') AS creation_date, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2019-12-28 09:41:17') AS change_date UNION ALL
SELECT 888724 AS id, 413 AS nrut, 'john smith' AS vendor_name, 'dispatched' AS state, null AS bedi, null AS flag, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2019-12-28 09:41:17') AS creation_date, PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %X', '2022-12-22 06:00:57') AS change_date
```

Comment: Hi - please don’t use images, use editable text so that someone can copy your data if they want to try a solution. Please also update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far and explain what specific issue you are facing

Comment: creation_date 2018-11-19 15:26:32 not shown in change data table. Pls update for completeness and clarity of the source data

Comment: Hi @ValNik, neither of the creation_date are present in the change data table. Sadly the change data table have only the modifications after the creation of the original data, this is one of the complexities. So, for the final audit data table I have to put the creation_date as the first change_date.

Thank you very much for your comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. Maybe not the most elegant solution but it works fine.

Can you suggest a better and optimized version? Thanks in advance.

```
WITH
  changes AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    ANY_VALUE(
    IF
      (column_change = 'bedi', new_value, NULL)) AS bedi,
    ANY_VALUE(
    IF
      (column_change = 'vendor_name', new_value, NULL)) AS vendor_name,
    ANY_VALUE(
    IF
      (column_change = 'nrut', SAFE_CAST(new_value AS INT64), NULL)) AS nrut,
    ANY_VALUE(
    IF
      (column_change = 'state', new_value, NULL)) AS state,
    ANY_VALUE(
    IF
      (column_change = 'flag', new_value, NULL)) AS flag,
    DATETIME_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATETIME(), SECOND) AS creation_date
  FROM
    `change_data_table`
  GROUP BY
    id,
    change_date ),
  recursive_without_1st_data AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    IFNULL(bedi, FIRST_VALUE(bedi IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS bedi,
    IFNULL(nrut, FIRST_VALUE(nrut IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS nrut,
    IFNULL(state, FIRST_VALUE(state IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS state,
    IFNULL(vendor_name, FIRST_VALUE(vendor_name IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS vendor_name,
    IFNULL(flag, FIRST_VALUE(flag IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS flag
  FROM
    changes ),
  col1 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    old_value AS bedi
  FROM
    `change_data_table`
  WHERE
    column_change = 'bedi' QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC) ),
  col2 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    old_value AS vendor_name
  FROM
    `change_data_table`
  WHERE
    column_change = 'vendor_name' QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC) ),
  col3 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    SAFE_CAST(old_value AS INT64) AS nrut
  FROM
    `change_data_table`
  WHERE
    column_change = 'nrut' QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC) ),
  col4 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    old_value AS state
  FROM
    `change_data_table`
  WHERE
    column_change = 'state' QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC) ),
  col5 AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    old_value AS flag
  FROM
    `change_data_table`
  WHERE
    column_change = 'flag' QUALIFY 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC) ),
  get_1st_data AS (
  SELECT
    d.id,
    d.creation_date AS change_date,
  IF
    (col1.change_date IS NOT NULL, col1.bedi,d.bedi) AS bedi,
  IF
    (col2.change_date IS NOT NULL, col2.vendor_name,d.vendor_name) AS vendor_name,
  IF
    (col3.change_date IS NOT NULL, col3.nrut,d.nrut) AS nrut,
  IF
    (col4.change_date IS NOT NULL, col4.state,d.state) AS state,
  IF
    (col5.change_date IS NOT NULL, col5.flag,d.flag) AS flag,
    d.creation_date
  FROM
    `transactional_data_table` d
  LEFT JOIN
    col1
  ON
    col1.id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN
    col2
  ON
    col2.id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN
    col3
  ON
    col3.id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN
    col4
  ON
    col4.id = d.id
  LEFT JOIN
    col5
  ON
    col5.id = d.id ),
  recursive_with_1st_data AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    change_date,
    IFNULL(bedi, FIRST_VALUE(bedi IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS bedi,
    IFNULL(nrut, FIRST_VALUE(nrut IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS nrut,
    IFNULL(state, FIRST_VALUE(state IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS state,
    IFNULL(vendor_name, FIRST_VALUE(vendor_name IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS vendor_name,
    IFNULL(flag, FIRST_VALUE(flag IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS flag,
    IFNULL(creation_date, FIRST_VALUE(creation_date IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY change_date ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS creation_date
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      creation_date AS change_date,
      bedi,
      vendor_name,
      nrut,
      state,
      flag,
      creation_date
    FROM
      get_1st_data
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      id,
      change_date,
      bedi,
      vendor_name,
      nrut,
      state,
      flag,
      NULL AS creation_date
    FROM
      recursive_without_1st_data ) )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  recursive_with_1st_data
ORDER BY
  id,
  change_date ASC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @aleretgub can you please explain your solution and if these are the correct results from the fiddle?
https://dbfiddle.uk/XbD-Epv3
Thank you in advance